# How do I target spinner (up/down arrows) inside number textinput in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to bind a handler to the click event for the little spinner (up/down arrows) that appear inside jQuery Mobile number textinput. See here:

[image: jQuery Mobile Number Textinput Spinner]

The above screenshot comes from the jQuery Mobile API documentation for the [Textinput Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/).

I can't target the entire input element because then the handler will be called on focus, and I don't want that.

Comment: What about handling the change event?

Comment: The change event for the input will fire the handler on focus, right?

Comment: It should only fire when the value actually changes, not on focus

Comment: You're right, sorry. I meant on blur in my comment above. But I really appreciate your suggestion, because I played around with the change event and I was able to achieve my goals by targeting specific events in a long chain from focus, keydown, keyup, change and blur. Took awhile to get it all to behave nicely.